MT4 trades and orders send to Telegram
Hi I have written the below code but keep getting the error in MetaEditor for the below code, anyone know what I have done incorrectly? Any assistance is appreciated.


// Include necessary libraries
#include <stdlib.mqh>
#include <stderror.mqh>
#include <WinUser32.mqh>

// Define your Telegram bot token and chat ID
string botToken = "7241390163:AAF_2395NQiPGXbWsXEI5a9nMvn_OccCCZQ";
string chatID = "1233229081";

// Function to send message to Telegram
void SendTelegramMessage(string message) {
   string url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botToken + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chatID + "&text=" + message;
   int timeout = 5000;
   char post[];
   int res = WebRequest("GET", url, "", 0, post, timeout);
   if (res != 200) {
      Print("Error sending message: ", GetLastError());
   }
}

// Function to send screenshot to Telegram
void SendTelegramScreenshot(string filePath) {
   string url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botToken + "/sendPhoto";
   int timeout = 5000;
   char post[];
   int res = WebRequest("POST", url, "chat_id=" + chatID + "&photo=@" + filePath, 0, post, timeout);
   if (res != 200) {
      Print("Error sending screenshot: ", GetLastError());
   }
}

// Function to capture screenshot
void CaptureScreenshot(string filePath) {
   WindowScreenShot(0, 0, 800, 600, filePath);
}

// Event handler for new orders
void OnTrade() {
   int totalOrders = OrdersTotal();
   for (int i = 0; i < totalOrders; i++) {
      if (OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)) {
         string message = "Order ID: " + IntegerToString(OrderTicket()) + "\nDirection: " + (OrderType() == OP_BUY ? "Buy" : "Sell") + "\nSymbol: " + OrderSymbol() + "\nPrice: " + DoubleToString(OrderOpenPrice(), 5) + "\nSL: " + DoubleToString(OrderStopLoss(), 5) + "\nTP: " + DoubleToString(OrderTakeProfit(), 5);
         SendTelegramMessage(message);
         string screenshotPath = "screenshot_" + IntegerToString(OrderTicket()) + ".png";
         CaptureScreenshot(screenshotPath);
         SendTelegramScreenshot(screenshotPath);
      }
   }
}

// Event handler for order modifications
void OnTradeModification() {
   int totalOrders = OrdersTotal();
   for (int i = 0; i < totalOrders; i++) {
      if (OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)) {
         string message = "Order ID: " + IntegerToString(OrderTicket()) + "\nDirection: " + (OrderType() == OP_BUY ? "Buy" : "Sell") + "\nSymbol: " + OrderSymbol() + "\nPrice: " + DoubleToString(OrderOpenPrice(), 5) + "\nSL: " + DoubleToString(OrderStopLoss(), 5) + "\nTP: " + DoubleToString(OrderTakeProfit(), 5) + "\nNote: Order price adjusted.";
         SendTelegramMessage(message);
         string screenshotPath = "screenshot_" + IntegerToString(OrderTicket()) + ".png";
         CaptureScreenshot(screenshotPath);
         SendTelegramScreenshot(screenshotPath);
      }
   }
}

// Event handler for closed orders
void OnTradeClose() {
   int totalOrders = OrdersHistoryTotal();
   for (int i = 0; i < totalOrders; i++) {
      if (OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY)) {
         string message = "Order ID: " + IntegerToString(OrderTicket()) + "\nClosing Price: " + DoubleToString(OrderClosePrice(), 5);
         SendTelegramMessage(message);
         string screenshotPath = "screenshot_" + IntegerToString(OrderTicket()) + "_close.png";
         CaptureScreenshot(screenshotPath);
         SendTelegramScreenshot(screenshotPath);
      }
   }
}

// Main function
int start() {
   OnTrade();
   OnTradeModification();
   OnTradeClose();
   return 0;
}

See error message screenshot attached.
I expected that when I do a trade it will send to telegram with a screenshot. Everytime I update an order it will send an update to telegram and if I closed a position it will send an update to telegram. All with trade details, etc.

You left your Private Bot Token in your code. You should revoke it ASAP by talking to the @BotFather. People might abuse the token.

Thanks for noting that. The bot has been deleted silly mistake.
